# scalability and performance in java web applications

Tags: java, performance, scalability

Let's say you want to build a web application with high scalability (over 10,000 simultanious users). How do you guarantee good and steady performance? What design patterns are recommendable? What are most frequent mistakes?

Are there frameworks that force yourself to write scalable code? Would you maybe consider php as frontend and Java as backend technology? Or is let's say JSF reasonable as well and it's all about your architecture? And how good is developing with Grails in that context?

Hope this thread is not too subjective but I like to gather some experiences of you :-)

Comment: you do want to google for *"C10K"* and Java.  Fascinating reads.  Now of course several languages/OSes can handle the C100K (10 times more connections than what you ask for) on not-so-beefy hardware ;)

Comment: Do you mean 10,000 simultaneous users as in: 1) 10,000+ HTTP hits per second or 2) 10,000 logged on users at once. For #1, see C10K; for #2, it's probably not an issue for any commonly used framework, assuming you aren't also trying to log all those users in in less than a few minutes.

Comment: I was thinking about the second point :-)

Comment: You would want to implement a thread pool or connection pool system, in this way then you can configure the maximum numbers of threads/connections per second (based on CPU and memory capacity). This is to maintain latency and to make sure that the server doesn't crash when there is a high load of requests coming in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to build a highly scalable application then it should be stateless and use shared nothing architecture as much as possible. If you share nothing between nodes and a node dont have a state then synchronization is minimum. There are several good web frameworks suitable for your requirements (Play Framework and Lift for Java, Django for Python, Ruby on Rails for Ruby).

As for JSF and related technologies, I dont think it would be wise to use them in your case. A good old request-responce is better.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your application to scale nicely and perform well then you need to have a Distributed Cache. Distributed cache can incredibly boost up application performance and for this purpose you can use any third party distributed cache like NCache.

Answer (score 0):

With so many simultaneous users (a situation I confess I've never encountered myself), what I think is the most important is to be able to load-balance your charge across many web servers.

If you want failover (which is probably a must-have), this means that you must be very careful about state : the more state you have, the more memory you need, and the more difficult it is to handle failover between servers : either you need to persist the session state in a location that is common to all the servers, or you need to replicate the state across servers.

So, I would choose an architecture where you don't need too much state on the server. IMHO, an action based framework is more suited to this kind of architecture than a component-based one, unless the state is handled at client side, with rich JavaScript components.